# How to automatically construct an mxn matrix with same coefficients and different pedices?

Tags: matrices, loops

Let's suppose I have an mxn matrix like the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\vth}{\vartheta}
\newcommand*{\vph}{\varphi}
\newcommand*{\pt}[1]{\left(#1\right)}

    \begin{document}
    
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}\vph_{11}&\vph_{12}&\vph_{13}&\vph_{14}&\vph_{15}&\vph_{16}&\dot{x}\pt{T}\\
\vph_{21}&\vph_{22}&\vph_{23}&\vph_{24}&\vph_{25}&\vph_{26}&\dot{y}\pt{T}\\
\vph_{31}&\vph_{32}&\vph_{33}&\vph_{34}&\vph_{35}&\vph_{36}&\dot{z}\pt{T}\\
\vph_{41}&\vph_{42}&\vph_{43}&\vph_{44}&\vph_{45}&\vph_{46}&\ddot{x}\pt{T}\\
\vph_{51}&\vph_{52}&\vph_{53}&\vph_{54}&\vph_{55}&\vph_{56}&\ddot{y}\pt{T}\\
\vph_{61}&\vph_{62}&\vph_{63}&\vph_{64}&\vph_{65}&\vph_{66}&\ddot{z}\pt{T}\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

How can I construct with a macro such a matrix in order to say, for example, that I just want rows 1, 3, 5 and columns 1, 3, 5?

I was thinking to something like \automatrix{\vph}{1;3;5}{1;3;5}, in which the first input is the common variable \vph, the second are the rows I want to include (and therefore the first pedices) and the third input the columns (second pedices).

If it is possible to include also an additional column in the "automatic" matrix like in the picture it would be great!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\vth}{\vartheta}
\newcommand*{\vph}{\varphi}
\newcommand*{\pt}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{+bmatrix}[cell{1-Z}{1-Y}={cmd={\vph_{\arabic{rownum}\arabic{colnum}}}}]
&&&&&&\dot{x}\pt{T}\\
&&&&&&\dot{x}\pt{T}\\
&&&&&&\dot{x}\pt{T}\\
&&&&&&\dot{x}\pt{T}\\
&&&&&&\dot{x}\pt{T}\\
&&&&&&\dot{x}\pt{T}\\
\end{+bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very elegant looking solution!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I just want rows 1, 3, 5 and columns 1, 3, 5

This can be interpreted in at least three ways.

1. All the entries in both rows 1,3,5 and columns 1,3,5, collapsed into a filled-in matrix.
2. All the entries in both rows 1,3,5 and columns 1,3,5, left as they are in the original matrix.
3. All the entries in either rows 1,3,5 or columns 1,3,5, left as they are in the original matrix.

I'll provide some code for each interpretation. In each case the code is probably suboptimal in terms of efficiency, but for personal use it should be sufficient. Much inspiration was taken from egreg's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/477749/208544).

Each command below has the following keys. Hopefully they are self explanatory.

- `symbol=<symbol>`, initially `\varphi`
- `rows=<integer>`
- `cols=<integer>`
- `row-spec=<comma list of integers>`
- `col-spec=<comma list of integers>`
- `final-col=<comma list of entries>`

### Approach 1

Here you can provide either `rows` or `row-spec` but not both. Similarly for `cols` and `col-spec`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand { \automatrix } { m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { mascolo/automatrix } { #1 }
    \mascolo_automatrix:
    \group_end:
  }

\tl_new:N \l__mascolo_automatrix_tl

\keys_define:nn { mascolo/automatrix }
  {
    symbol    .tl_set:N    = \l__mascolo_automatrix_symbol_tl,
    symbol    .initial:n   = \varphi,
    rows      .int_set:N   = \l__mascolo_automatrix_totrows_int,
    cols      .int_set:N   = \l__mascolo_automatrix_totcols_int,
    row-spec  .clist_set:N = \l__mascolo_automatrix_rowspec_clist,
    col-spec  .clist_set:N = \l__mascolo_automatrix_colspec_clist,
    final-col .clist_set:N = \l__mascolo_automatrix_finalcol_clist,
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mascolo_automatrix:
  {
    \int_compare:nT
      {
        \int_max:nn { \l__mascolo_automatrix_totrows_int }
          { \l__mascolo_automatrix_totcols_int } > \value{MaxMatrixCols}
      }
      {
        \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}
          {
            \int_max:nn { \l__mascolo_automatrix_totrows_int }
              { \l__mascolo_automatrix_totcols_int }
          }
      }
    \clist_if_empty:NTF \l__mascolo_automatrix_rowspec_clist
      {
        \int_step_function:nN { \l__mascolo_automatrix_totrows_int }
          \__mascolo_automatrix_row:n
      }
      {
        \int_step_inline:nn
          { \fp_eval:n { max( \l__mascolo_automatrix_rowspec_clist ) } }
          {
            \clist_if_in:NnTF \l__mascolo_automatrix_rowspec_clist { ##1 }
              { \__mascolo_automatrix_row:n { ##1 } }
              { \clist_pop:NN \l__mascolo_automatrix_finalcol_clist \l_tmpa_tl }
          }
      }
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \l__mascolo_automatrix_tl
    \end{bmatrix}
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mascolo_automatrix_row:n
  {
    \clist_if_empty:NTF \l__mascolo_automatrix_colspec_clist
      { \__mascolo_automatrix_row_nocolspec:n { #1 } }
      { \__mascolo_automatrix_row_withcolspec:n { #1 } }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mascolo_automatrix_row_nocolspec:n
  {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrix_tl
      { \l__mascolo_automatrix_symbol_tl \sb{ #1,1 } }
    \int_step_inline:nnn { 2 } { \l__mascolo_automatrix_totcols_int }
      {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrix_tl
          {
            &
            \l__mascolo_automatrix_symbol_tl \sb{ #1,##1 }
          }
      }
    \clist_pop:NNTF \l__mascolo_automatrix_finalcol_clist \l_tmpa_tl
      {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrix_tl { & }
        \tl_put_right:NV \l__mascolo_automatrix_tl \l_tmpa_tl
      }
      { }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrix_tl { \\ }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mascolo_automatrix_row_withcolspec:n
  {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrix_tl
      {
        \l__mascolo_automatrix_symbol_tl
        \sb{ #1,\clist_item:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrix_colspec_clist{1} }
      }
    \int_step_inline:nnn { 2 } { \clist_count:N \l__mascolo_automatrix_colspec_clist }
      {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrix_tl
          {
            &
            \l__mascolo_automatrix_symbol_tl
            \sb{ #1,\clist_item:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrix_colspec_clist { ##1 } }
          }
      }
    \clist_pop:NNTF \l__mascolo_automatrix_finalcol_clist \l_tmpa_tl
          {
            \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrix_tl { & }
            \tl_put_right:NV \l__mascolo_automatrix_tl \l_tmpa_tl
          }
          { }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrix_tl { \\ }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\automatrix{rows=4,cols=5,symbol=\xi,final-col={w,x,y,z}}
\quad
\automatrix{cols=5,row-spec={2,4},final-col={w,x,y,z}}
\]
\[
\automatrix{rows=4,col-spec={2,4}}
\quad
\automatrix{row-spec={2,4},col-spec={2,4}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: try1]

### Approach 2

Here the keys `rows` and `cols` are required since we need to know in advance how big the original matrix is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand { \automatrixalt } { m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { mascolo/automatrixalt } { #1 }
    \mascolo_automatrixalt:
    \group_end:
  }

\tl_new:N \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_tl

\keys_define:nn { mascolo/automatrixalt }
  {
    symbol    .tl_set:N         = \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_symbol_tl,
    symbol    .initial:n        = \varphi,
    rows      .int_set:N        = \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_totrows_int,
    rows      .value_required:n = true,
    cols      .int_set:N        = \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_totcols_int,
    cols      .value_required:n = true,
    row-spec  .clist_set:N      = \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_rowspec_clist,
    col-spec  .clist_set:N      = \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_colspec_clist,
    final-col .clist_set:N      = \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_finalcol_clist,
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mascolo_automatrixalt:
  {
    \int_compare:nT
      {
        \int_max:nn { \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_totrows_int }
          { \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_totcols_int } > \value{MaxMatrixCols}
      }
      {
        \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}
          {
            \int_max:nn { \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_totrows_int }
              { \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_totcols_int }
          }
      }
    \clist_if_empty:NTF \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_rowspec_clist
      {
        \int_step_function:nN { \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_totrows_int }
          \__mascolo_automatrixalt_row:n
      }
      {
        \int_step_inline:nn
          { \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_totrows_int }
          {
            \clist_if_in:NnTF \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_rowspec_clist { ##1 }
              { \__mascolo_automatrixalt_row:n { ##1 } }
              {
                \clist_pop:NN \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_finalcol_clist \l_tmpa_tl
                \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_tl { \\ }
              }
          }
      }
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_tl
    \end{bmatrix}
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mascolo_automatrixalt_row:n
  {
    \clist_if_empty:NTF \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_colspec_clist
      { \__mascolo_automatrixalt_row_nocolspec:n { #1 } }
      { \__mascolo_automatrixalt_row_withcolspec:n { #1 } }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mascolo_automatrixalt_row_nocolspec:n
  {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_tl
      { \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_symbol_tl \sb{ #1,1 } }
    \int_step_inline:nnn { 2 } { \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_totcols_int }
      {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_tl
          {
            &
            \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_symbol_tl \sb{ #1,##1 }
          }
      }
    \clist_pop:NNTF \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_finalcol_clist \l_tmpa_tl
      {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_tl { & }
        \tl_put_right:NV \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_tl \l_tmpa_tl
      }
      { }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_tl { \\ }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mascolo_automatrixalt_row_withcolspec:n
  {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_tl
      {
        \clist_if_in:NnTF \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_colspec_clist { 1 }
          { \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_symbol_tl \sb{ #1,1 } }
          { \phantom{ \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_symbol_tl \sb{ #1,1 } } }
      }
    \int_compare:nNnT { \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_totcols_int } > { 1 }
      {
        \int_step_inline:nnn { 2 } { \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_totcols_int }
          {
            \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_tl
              {
                &
                \clist_if_in:NnTF \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_colspec_clist { ##1 }
                  { \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_symbol_tl \sb{ #1,##1 } }
                  { \phantom{ \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_symbol_tl \sb{ #1,##1 } } }
              }
          }
      }
    \clist_pop:NNTF \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_finalcol_clist \l_tmpa_tl
      {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_tl { & }
        \tl_put_right:NV \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_tl \l_tmpa_tl
      }
      { }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrixalt_tl { \\ }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\automatrixalt{rows=4,cols=5,symbol=\xi,final-col={w,x,y,z}}
\quad
\automatrixalt{rows=4,cols=5,row-spec={2,4},final-col={w,x,y,z}}
\]
\[
\automatrixalt{rows=4,cols=5,col-spec={2,4}}
\quad
\automatrixalt{rows=4,cols=5,row-spec={2,4},col-spec={2,4}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: try2]

### Approach 3

As with approach 2, the keys `rows` and `cols` are required here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand { \automatrixaltii } { m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { mascolo/automatrixaltii } { #1 }
    \mascolo_automatrixaltii:
    \group_end:
  }

\tl_new:N \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_tl

\keys_define:nn { mascolo/automatrixaltii }
  {
    symbol    .tl_set:N         = \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_symbol_tl,
    symbol    .initial:n        = \varphi,
    rows      .int_set:N        = \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_totrows_int,
    rows      .value_required:n = true,
    cols      .int_set:N        = \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_totcols_int,
    cols      .value_required:n = true,
    row-spec  .clist_set:N      = \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_rowspec_clist,
    col-spec  .clist_set:N      = \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_colspec_clist,
    final-col .clist_set:N      = \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_finalcol_clist,
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mascolo_automatrixaltii:
  {
    \int_compare:nNnT
      {
        \int_max:nn { \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_totrows_int }
          { \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_totcols_int }
      }
      > { \value{MaxMatrixCols} }
      {
        \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}
          {
            \int_max:nn { \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_totrows_int }
              { \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_totcols_int }
          }
      }
    \clist_if_empty:NTF \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_rowspec_clist
      {
        \int_step_function:nN { \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_totrows_int }
          \__mascolo_automatrixaltii_row:n
      }
      {
        \int_step_inline:nn
          { \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_totrows_int }
          {
            \clist_if_in:NnTF \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_rowspec_clist { ##1 }
              { \__mascolo_automatrixaltii_row_nocolspec:n { ##1 } }
              { \__mascolo_automatrixaltii_row_notinrowspec:n { ##1 } }
          }
      }
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_tl
    \end{bmatrix}
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mascolo_automatrixaltii_row:n
  {
    \clist_if_empty:NTF \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_colspec_clist
      { \__mascolo_automatrixaltii_row_nocolspec:n { #1 } }
      { \__mascolo_automatrixaltii_row_notinrowspec:n { #1 } }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mascolo_automatrixaltii_row_nocolspec:n
  {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_tl
      { \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_symbol_tl \sb{ #1,1 } }
    \int_step_inline:nnn { 2 } { \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_totcols_int }
      {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_tl
          {
            &
            \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_symbol_tl \sb{ #1,##1 }
          }
      }
    \clist_pop:NNTF \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_finalcol_clist \l_tmpa_tl
      {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_tl { & }
        \tl_put_right:NV \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_tl \l_tmpa_tl
      }
      { }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_tl { \\ }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mascolo_automatrixaltii_row_notinrowspec:n
  {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_tl
      {
        \clist_if_in:NnTF \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_colspec_clist { 1 }
          { \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_symbol_tl \sb{ #1,1 } }
          { \phantom{ \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_symbol_tl \sb{ #1,1 } } }
      }
    \int_compare:nNnT { \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_totcols_int } > { 1 }
      {
        \int_step_inline:nnn { 2 } { \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_totcols_int }
          {
            \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_tl
              {
                &
                \clist_if_in:NnTF \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_colspec_clist { ##1 }
                  { \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_symbol_tl \sb{ #1,##1 } }
                  { \phantom{ \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_symbol_tl \sb{ #1,##1 } } }
              }
          }
      }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_tl { \\ }
    \clist_pop:NN \l__mascolo_automatrixaltii_finalcol_clist \l_tmpa_tl
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\automatrixaltii{rows=4,cols=5,symbol=\xi,final-col={w,x,y,z}}
\quad
\automatrixaltii{rows=4,cols=5,row-spec={2,4},final-col={w,x,y,z}}
\]
\[
\automatrixaltii{rows=4,cols=5,col-spec={2,4}}
\quad
\automatrixaltii{rows=4,cols=5,row-spec={2,4},col-spec={2,4}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: try3]